# Add Tuple3 to a mutable Set in Scala

Tags: scala, set, mutable

I have already looked at adding tuples to a Set in scala but nothing seems to work in my case

```
 val mySet = mutable.HashSet[(String, String, String)]
 val myTuple = ("hi", "hello", "there")

mySet ++= myTuple
mySet += myTuple  // Expects String instead of (String, String, String)
mySet :+ myTuple
mySet :: myTuple
```

Except the second rest of them are compiler errors. How can I add a Tuple to a mutable Set in scala?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend using `empty` to create an empty collection:

```
val mySet = mutable.HashSet.empty[(String, String, String)]
```

This avoids the issue that you found, and makes the intent of the expression clear.

Answer (score 2):

Adding parens at the end fixed it:

```
val mySet = mutable.HashSet[(String, String, String)]()
mySet += myTuple
```